# Issue with min - max - mean task

Tags: influxdb-2

I have a bucket (`homeassistant`) that collects info from a temperature / humidity sensor.

Of course, I want to downsample his data to min/max/mean of previous day.

Inspired by [this post](https://community.influxdata.com/t/task-daily-min-max/22442/4), I created a new bucket `downsample` and two tasks for the moment:

```yaml
option task = {name: "BALCONE_MAX", cron: "0 0 * * *"}
option v = {timeRangeStart: -1d, timeRangeStop: now()}

from(bucket: "homeassistant")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r.entity_id == "0x00158d00067beedf_temperature")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
    |> yield(name: "max")
    |> to(bucket: "downsample", org: "sineverba")
```

And

```yaml
option task = {name: "BALCONE_MIN", cron: "0 0 * * *"}
option v = {timeRangeStart: -1d, timeRangeStop: now()}

from(bucket: "homeassistant")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r.entity_id == "0x00158d00067beedf_temperature")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
    |> yield(name: "min")
    |> to(bucket: "downsample", org: "sineverba")
```

They run both at 00:00 and save min and max in **same bucket.**

But today I checked and... I have only a single point (only the min value, in reality), not the max.

Is it possible to save both value inside same bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You can save both values to the same bucket, in one task. The key is to have different fields for min and max values, otherwise the value gets overwritten by the latter `to`.

```js
option task = {name: "BALCONE_MAX", cron: "0 0 * * *"}
option v = {timeRangeStart: -1d, timeRangeStop: now()}

data = from(bucket: "homeassistant")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.entity_id == "0x00158d00067beedf_temperature")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
min = data
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> set(key: "_field", value: "value_min")
  |> to(bucket: "downsample", org: "sineverba")
  |> yield(name: "min")
max = data
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> set(key: "_field", value: "value_max")
  |> to(bucket: "downsample", org: "sineverba")
  |> yield(name: "max")
```

Answer (score 0):

I enountered a similar problem where I wanted to compute several min and max values, but for **multiple fields at the same time** to reduce the number of queries.

I found it helpful to use the `map` function to append `_min` or `_max` to the field names. For example, for the field `temp_hotwater`, I get `temp_hotwater_min` and `temp_hotwater_max` and also `temp_outside_min` and `temp_outside_max` for `temp_outside` - all with one query.

```js
data = from(bucket: "house")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "heatpump")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temp_hotwater" or r["_field"] == "temp_outside")

data
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _field: r._field + "_max"}))
    |> to(bucket: "house_daily", org: "home")
    |> yield(name: "max")

data
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _field: r._field + "_min"}))
    |> to(bucket: "house_daily", org: "home")
    |> yield(name: "min")
```